# Use htaccess to redirect wordpress homepage to subpage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Sorry for what is probably a simple thing, but not for me...

I need to redirect all requests for the domain root to a specific page on my wordpress site, without breaking everything else.  What I've been trying so far is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com/my-target-page/$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^ http://mydomain.com/my-target-page/ [R=301,L]
```

It does indeed redirect to the  url mydomain/my-target-page/  , but it doesn't resolve to anything.  I think that wordpress doesn't work with this, and I'm not even close, but can't wrap my head around what I should do here.  Help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do what you are after:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /my-target-page/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: awesome, simple and helpful

Comment: 2019 and still usefull